# Laravel Scopes in query buulder

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Can we apply global or local scopes in Laravel's Query Builder like you can in Eloquent? I couldn't find information about this in the official documentation. Any insights on how to achieve similar functionality with Query Builder would be helpful. Because i want to reduce soft delete where clauses from queries.

Comment: you can follow this beautiful article.
https://copyprogramming.com/howto/how-to-make-a-scope-with-a-raw-sql-query-in-laravel-7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Query Builder scopes you can define a macro and include it manually.

Define your "scope" macro

```
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder;
​
Builder::macro('notTrashed', function () {
    return $this->whereNull('deleted_at');
});
```

and then use it with the query builder

```
$managers = DB::table('users')->notTrashed()->get();
```

Not a convenient as global scopes which are included automatically, but then global scopes are a pain when you *don't* want them and you have to exclude them by calling `withoutGlobalScopes()`.

And although it does not remove the need to add some code to check for soft deleted rows it does reduce it.